# Wordpress Failed to load jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wp-admin

In wp-admin, all actions related to jQuery are broken

[http://up.persianscript.ir/uploads3/bcc1-Capture.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPv0I.png)

How could I fix it?

I tested the code below but the problem didn’t work

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If you don't get an answer here you may want to head over to the Wordpress dedicated Stack Exchange here >>> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Some plugin can conflict WordPress jQuery. Try with disabling plugin one by one and check.

Answer (score 0):

`CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS` is the constant that tells wordpress to, concatenate all of the dependencies into one URL and load it together.

if you have problems with it, it is probably because of some javascript conflict in theme or plugin.

you should isolate the problem and fix it